# Поиск чётных элементов в двумерном массиве

Tags: python

У меня есть двумерный массив. Мне нужно подсчитать количество чётных его элементов и вывести это количество на экран. Как это сделать?

```
import random
random.seed()
m = input('Количество столбцов > ') # количество столбцов
n = input('Количество строк > ') # количество рядов
M = [[random.randint(-100, 100) for _ in range(eval(m))] for _ in range(eval(n))]
for V in M:
  for e in V:
    print(e, end=', ')
  print()
```

Comment: Не надо использовать eval таким образом. На самом деле, его вообще лучше никогда не использовать. А для того, чтобы привести строку к числу, используйте int(n)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import random
random.seed()
m = input('Количество столбцов > ') # количество столбцов
n = input('Количество строк > ') # количество рядов
M = [[random.randint(-100, 100) for _ in range(eval(m))] for _ in range(eval(n))]
for V in M:
    for e in V:
        print(e, end=', ')
    print()

even = 0
for V in M:
    for e in V:
        if e % 2 == 0:
            even += 1
print(even)
```

P.s. в этом сообществе принято излагать свой вариант решения, каким бы он ни был, чтобы его можно было подправить, а не просить решать задачу за вас

Answer (score 1):

```
import random
random.seed()
m = input('Количество столбцов > ') # количество столбцов
n = input('Количество строк > ') # количество рядов
M = [[random.randint(-100, 100) for _ in range(int(m))] for _ in range(int(n))]

count = 0

for V in M:
  for e in V:
    if not e & 1:
        count += 1
print(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну на коленке как-то так:

```
import random


def even_values(mtx: list) -> list:
    new = []
    for row in range(mtx.__len__()):
        for col in range(mtx[row].__len__()):
            if mtx[row][col] % 2 == 0:
                new.append(mtx[row][col])
    return new


if __name__ == '__main__':
    random.seed()
    m = int(input('Количество столбцов > '))  # количество столбцов
    n = int(input('Количество строк > '))  # количество рядов
    print(even_values([[random.randint(-100, 100) for _ in range(m)] for _ in range(n)]).__len__())
```

Или без создания самой матрицы:

```
random.seed()
m = int(input('Количество столбцов > '))  # количество столбцов
n = int(input('Количество строк > '))  # количество рядов
print(sum(1 if random.randint(-100, 100) % 2 == 0 else 0 for _ in range(m * n)))
```